# Why is my lazy recursive Clojure function being realized?

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to solve a 4Clojure problem (sequence reductions), and I've hit a wall. The problem is to reimplement the `reductions` function.

It seems to me like this function *should* return a lazy sequence, but it doesn't - evaluating `(take 5 (redux + (range)))` results in an infinite loop.

Here's my code:

```
(defn redux
  ([f coll] 
      (redux f (first coll) (rest coll)))
  ([f val coll] 
      ((fn red [val coll s]
           (if (empty? coll)
               s
               (lazy-seq
                  (let [val (f val (first coll))]
                    (red val 
                         (rest coll)
                         (conj s val))))))
       val coll [val])))
```

Why is this function not returning a lazy sequence?

Comment: I don't have time to answer fully, but look at your code and ask yourself, when is an element actually being added somewhere? You'll notice that it's not. It's just a series of thunks (lazy-seq) that calls `red` ... you should probably have `cons` in your code somewhere if you have `lazy-seq`, generally speaking, as this actually creates the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few misconceptions in the code. noisesmith pointed out on #clojurians chat (and Josh's comment stated as well) the following points:

1. There is no step in the above function where you can evaluate the head and not the tail of a list.
2. It does an immediate self recursion, and to get the n+1 element, you need to do the recursive call.
3. `lazy-seq` should always have a call to `cons` or some similar function that lets you return the next item of the list without recurring.
4. `conj` is never lazy, and vectors are never lazy.
5. You cannot append to a list without realizing the entire thing.

I modified the code to the following:

```
(fn redux
  ([f coll] 
      (redux f (first coll) (rest coll)))
  ([f val coll] 
      (cons val
        ((fn red [val coll]
           (lazy-seq
             (when-not (empty? coll)
               (let [val (f val (first coll))]
                 (cons val (red val (rest coll)))))))
          val coll))))
```

Note the use of `cons` instead of `conj`.

Comment: Looks good, but why are you using the inner `fn`? You can just make `redux` recursive, like the [clojure.core](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L7089) implementation does.

Comment: @AlephAleph @Josh The extra cons and inner fn were a quick hack to get the first unevaluated `val` at the start of the list. I've been staring at the problem for too long to come up with a more elegant solution atm.

Comment: @LincolnBergeson FWIW the more elegant solution looks like `(defn redux [f val coll] (lazy-seq (cons val (... (redux ...)))))`.